# How to define a route to a controller in a sub folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

This is the route:

```
devise_for :users
  post 'users/sessions/destroy_and_create'
```

This is the folder structure:

```
controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb
```

And this is the error I get:

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound (Could not find devise mapping for path "/users/sessions/destroy_and_create"
```

Comment: Try with `post 'users/sessions#destroy_and_create'`.

Comment: @SebastianPalma This leads to this error when starting the server: `Missing :controller key on routes definition, please check your routes. (ArgumentError)`

Comment: I think you also need to add in your ```routes.rb``` 
this: ```devise_for :users, controllers: {
      sessions: 'users/sessions'
  }```

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need to add in your `routes.rb` this:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { 
  sessions: 'users/sessions' 
}
```

Comment: But I'm not trying to set login to root page.